# combine multiple row numbers when update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

my table looks something like this

```
id(int), inorder(int), outorder(int), parentID(int)
```

My stored procedure

```
    @parentID int,
    @inorder int, 
    @outorder int
BEGIN
    UPDATE myOrders 
    SET inorder = @inorder, outorders 
    WHERE id = @parentID
END
```

I want to do it combine all inorder and outoder int values of the any rows that have the parentID.

Something like:

```
UPDATE myOrders 
SET inorder = (SELECT inorder FROM myOrders WHERE parentID = @ parentID) + @inorder, 
    (SELECT outorder FROM myOrders WHERE parentID = @ parentID) + @outorder 
WHERE id = @parentID
```

Of course this doesn't work, is there a way to do this?

Example scenario

```
1, 0, 0, null
2, 10, 50, 1
3, 100, 90, 1
4, 80, 100, 1
```

After executed, row with id 1 becomes

```
1, 190, 240, null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE statement is not looking right. In your Update statement, you have set Second update column OUTORDER. Also, You have added outorder instead of @outorder.

As per your requirement, I think there's not need for variables `@inorder` and `@outorder`. Only you need to supply `@parentID`. I have done `sum of Inorder and Outorder Where parentid is 1` and assigned the value to respective `inorder and outorder where id = 1`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE myOrders SET inorder = (SELECT sum(inorder) FROM myOrders WHERE parentID = @parentID), 
outorder = (SELECT sum(outorder) FROM myOrders WHERE parentID = @parentID) 
WHERE id = @parentID
```

Comment: hi theres whats the problem??

Comment: oh thats a typo. I edited it. is my query correct to do this kind of update?

Comment: Check your update statement after '@inorder,' you have select statement adding '@outorder' value but you are not assigning to any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might like this alternate approach :

```
;WITH cte_update
     AS (SELECT t2.id,
                Sum(t1.inorder + t2.inorder)   inorder,
                Sum(t1.outorder + t2.outorder) outorder
         FROM   @temp t1
                JOIN @temp t2
                  ON t2.id = t1.parentID
         WHERE  t2.id = @parentid
         GROUP  BY t2.id)

UPDATE t1
SET    t1.inorder = t2.inorder + @inorder,
       t1.outorder = t2.outorder + @outorder
FROM   @temp t1
       JOIN cte_update t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
```

`cte_update` will sum up the `inorder` and `outorder` of both parent and child record. Ultimately, joining the CTE and physical table to update desired record.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly based off your example then you want to set the parent record fields to be the sum of the child records.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #myOrder(id int, inOrder int, outOrder int , parentID int)

INSERT INTO #myOrder
SELECT 1, 0, 0, null UNION
SELECT 2, 10, 50, 1 UNION
SELECT 4, 80, 100, 1 UNION
SELECT 5, 0, 0, NULL UNION
SELECT 6, 40, 80, 5 UNION
SELECT 7, 60, 90, 5 UNION
SELECT 8, 0, 0, NULL UNION
SELECT 9, 120, 70, 8 UNION
SELECT 10, 50, 80, 8

SELECT * FROM #myOrder

DECLARE @parentId AS INT = 1

UPDATE #myOrder
SET inOrder = x.inOrderSum, outOrder = x.outOrderSum
FROM #myOrder
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(inOrder) inOrderSum, SUM(outOrder) outOrderSum FROM #myOrder WHERE parentID = @parentId) X
WHERE id = @parentId

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM #myOrder

DROP TABLE #myOrder
```